# permissions of a folder to change to use grunt

Tags: permissions, sudo, npm, grunt

I know it must have been answered somewhere but I cannot find it.

I want to install Grunt in a project directory, on my computer, on a virtual volume (I am in dual boot with Windows, and the directory I am working on is on a third volume, not the Windows one).

When I try to install it there it constantly return errors and I cannot use Grunt, even though I am using sudo. It still returns :

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
(... plenty of other lines of npm ERR! ...))
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Now when I try to do it with the same project but after having copied it in my /home/username  volume-directory, then it works fine.

What should I do ?

Thanks!

Comment: /home is a linux location. If you are trying to install Linux software on a windows volume what do you expect to happen when you do that?! Won't work. Ever.

Comment: Hi Rinzwind. Thank you for your time. I guess I was not clear enough. I am working in a third volume, not the Windows one, just a volume where I save my documents.

Comment: and that volume is in ext3 or ext4?

Comment: It's on 'FAT32'. Or at least it says when I look at it with Disks. Now if I right-click and check with the Files properties, it says: 'Filesystem type: msdos' (?!) (I am really new to Linux, so perdon my lack of knowledge ;) )

Comment: Then see my first comment. You can not install linux software and use it from a windows filesystem. You can only do that if you convince Microsoft to support posix/linux.

Comment: Okay, thank you Rinzwind. I thought you were talking about the partition where the Windows OS is installed.